# Disable ftp access by browser - vsftpd and ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, vsftpd

I'm trying to disable browser ftp access via the url ftp://myip but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What issue are you facing? Why do you want to disable access via browser? With other clients it should work? Your Browser is just another FTP Client.... Btw: Firefox will drop ftp support with version 77.

Comment: is it safe to let ftp:// go live?

Comment: FTP is never safe, but you did not answer any of my questions ?! Please edit your question and add details. You might want to [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to improve your question ...

Comment: I want to disable browser access because I guess it's not the most secure thing.